# Vue.js eslint Parsing error .: unexpected token

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I am getting this error on a  state.js file  ( at => in the const profile )
cannot understand why ... thanks for feedback

```
const credentials = {
  email: '',
  password: ''
}
const profile = {
=>    userId: '',
  gender: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  address: '',
  zipCode: '',
  city: '',
  country: 'France',
  musician: false,
  musicInstruments: [],
  yearsPlaying: 0
}
export default {
  credentials,
  profile
}
```

standard eslint conf from vue-cli . webpack init

**.eslintrc.js**

```
// https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
  },
  extends: [
    // https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue#priority-a-essential-error-prevention
    // consider switching to `plugin:vue/strongly-recommended` or `plugin:vue/recommended` for stricter rules.
    'plugin:vue/essential', 
    // https://github.com/standard/standard/blob/master/docs/RULES-en.md
    'standard'
  ],
  // required to lint *.vue files
  plugins: [
    'vue'
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
    // allow async-await
    'generator-star-spacing': 'off',
    // allow debugger during development
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off'
  }
}
```

**the error**

```
file: 'file:///Users/yves/Developments/WIP/FIREBASE/vue-firebase-tutorial-store-user/src/store/state.js'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Parsing error: Unexpected token

[0m [90m 4 | [39m}[0m
[0m [90m 5 | [39m[36mconst[39m profil[0m
[0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 6 | [39m[36mexport[39m [36mdefault[39m {[0m
[0m [90m   | [39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
[0m [90m 7 | [39m  credentials[0m
[0m [90m 8 | [39m}[0m
[0m [90m 9 | [39m[0m'
at: '6,1'
source: 'eslint'
code: 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn on ES6:

```
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
```

should be:

```
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    ecmaVersion: 6
  },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...  help for single state.js file ,  no error using modules

Comment: This isn't working for me. I tried `ecmaVersion` set to `6` and to `2017`.

Comment: Just in case someone made the same mistake as me, I got a `Unexpected token in JSON at position` error when I tried running `yarn install` which was easily fixed by removing the comma at the end of `"ecmaVersion": 6`